# Loading Excel into Datatable without header

Tags: c#, sql, xlsx, import-from-excel

I wrote a code in C# to copy data from excel to sql table. The problem is that it's skipping the first two rows while importing data to sql table. If I insert HDR=No it skip first row only. How can I fix this so it doesn't skip any rows?

```
string excelfilepath = @"C:\Users\atola\Desktop\BS\ctest.xlsx";
       string ssqltable = "student";
// make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if have different
string myexceldataquery = "select  * from [sheet1$]";
try
{
    //create our connection strings
    string sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelfilepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'";


    string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=MCKSQLDW1;Initial Catalog=AS400_Integration;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
    //execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
    string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
    sqlconn.Open();
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlconn.Close();
    //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
    OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
    oledbconn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
    }

    oledbconn.Close();
}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Maybe try using a named range in Excel instead of a sheet name.

Comment: I cannot use range as number of records will be different every time

Answer (score 0):

I used do while instead of while and my problem got solved.Because the datareader works in Forward Direction only, so While calling in while loop , it already move i++ and when we write it to server, it writes the second row.